# What do you call someone who calculates all their actions based on the future outcome and neglects the present usefulness?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

There are some individuals, when they want to buy something like an automobile or home or similar things think about the future market for selling it, and neglect its present advantages and usefulness, or in the relationship calculate how much they are able to use that individual for their own future interest, even if that person is unpleasant. 
I don’t know if the word “opportunist “or “futuristic individual” could be used.

Comment: Someone *who knows the price of everything, but the value of nothing*?

Answer (score 1):

If, as you said," in relationship {they} calculate how much they are able to use that individual for their own future interest, even if that person is unpleasant", then they are not *opportunists* but rather  *manipulators* for an *opportunist* is the one who "exploits circumstances to gain immediate advantage rather than being guided by consistent principles or plans".

Answer (score 1):

> **CALCULATING** *adjective*
>
> **2**: marked by prudent analysis or by shrewd consideration of self-interest :  scheming

from [**Merriam-Webster Dictionary *online***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calculating)

Answer (score 0):

The general term for someone who looks more towards the long-term than the short term is **farsighted** (by analogy to physical vision).

My only hesitation is that this has a positive connotation, and it sounds like you might be looking more for something with a negative connotation.  Looking towards the long-term is generally considered a positive in the English-speaking world so it may be difficult to find a pejorative with this same meaning.